# Python: вывод числа с разбиением на триады

Tags: python, print, format

Необходимо вывести число с разделением на триады. Красивого решения я не нашел.
Вот вариант, который выдается за лучшее решение:

```
a = 300_000_000
b = 27.6
c = a/b
print('{:,}'.format(c))
```

Результат вывода: **10,869,565.217391305**

***Вопрос.*** Можно ли сформатировать число так, чтобы триады были разделены разделителем и количество
цифр после точки было наперед задано? Например, две:

```
10,869,565.21
```

Answer (score 4):

Существует управляющий форматом символ `n`, который выводит число в формате текущей локали. Это самый верный способ, так как все пользователи увидят с теми разделителями, которые приняты в их стране.

```py
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8")

numint = 200_000_000

print(f'{numint:n}')
```

Вывод:

```py
200 000 000
```

С `float` могут быть проблемы, так как для больших чисел выведется экспоненциальная форма. В этом случае можно использовать `locale.format_string`:

```py
print(locale.format_string('%.2f', numint, grouping=True))
```

Вывод:

```py
200 000 000,00
```

Если нужен какой-то определённый формат вывода, подберите нужную локаль и установите не `locale.LC_ALL`, а `locale.LC_NUMERIC`. Это не повлияет на обычный вывод чисел, будет работать только с функциями модуля `locale`.

В большинстве случаев это правильнее, чем использовать `replace`.

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант

```
print(f'{c:,.2f}')
```

Comment: А как быть в случае, если число целое и его надо разбить на триады и вывести определенной длины?

с = 90_000
print(f'{c:,10d}')

Не работает.  Как быть в этой ситуации?

Comment: @GreyKoshak Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour . Если у вас есть другие вопросы - задайте новый вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(f'{c:,.2f}'.replace(',', ' '))
10 849 909.58
```

И, если надо пробелы, то можно так.
**Спасибо**, вполне в стиле питона.