# Форматировать зарплату: отделить пробелом тысячи

Tags: python, python-3.x

есть список зарплат, нужно для удобства отформатировать число- отделить тысячи пробелом.
есть код:

```
salary = '30000'
salary2 = salary.replace('0000', '0 000')
print(salary2)
```

получается то что надо: 30 000
, но проблема в том, что если будет зарплата например 300000, то на выходе я получу 30 0000
как решить проблему форматирования зарплат для всех уровней, и с 3мя нолями вроде 9000 и с 5ю нолями вроде 300000?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670125/python-format-string-thousand-separator-with-spaces

Comment: А если три миллиона? То числом тысяч будет 3000?

Comment: 3 000 000 работает отлично, спасибо!

Comment: хотя 3 млн зарплаты не видел))

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python: вывод числа с разбиением на триады](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1281983/python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если всегда нужно именно количество **тысяч**, то можно так:

```
def get_formated_salary(salary):
    return f'{salary[:-3]} {salary[-3:]}'

print(get_formated_salary('30000'))
print(get_formated_salary('300000'))
print(get_formated_salary('3000000'))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 30 000 
> 300 000 
> 3000 000
> ```

---

Для общего случая, можно просто последовательно разбивать строку с зарплатой на блоки по 3:

```
def get_formated_salary(salary):
    salary_blocks = []
    while len(salary) > 3:
        salary_blocks.append(salary[-3:])
        salary = salary[:-3]
    salary_blocks = ' '.join(salary_blocks[::-1])
    return f'{salary} {salary_blocks}'

print(get_formated_salary('30000'))
print(get_formated_salary('300000'))
print(get_formated_salary('3000000'))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> 30 000 
> 300 000 
> 3 000 000
> ```

Comment: 3 миллиона неверно отображает. должно быть 3 000 000

Comment: @strawdog по ТЗ этого непонятно, вроде человек хочет количество тысяч, а в трех миллионах три тысячи тысяч, сейчас сделаю еще общий вариант