# Как выводить числа в чат через точку? ( 10.000, а не 10000) disnake.py sqlite3

Tags: python

Нужна помощь, нужно что бы бот из базы данных, выводил числа через точку или запятую.

Обычно он делает это так: 1000, а нужно: 1.000

Comment: См например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1281983/1365. Это в целом вопрос скорее про форматирование строк средствами Python, а не про sql или discord.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Python: вывод числа с разбиением на триады](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1281983/python-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b4%d1%8b)

Answer (score 1):

Код по аналогии с кодом из [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1282041/1365), адаптировано под ваш случай (целое число, разделитель разрядов - точка):

```
x = 19783598745098604980923980423490945098398569485694865095480678
print(f"{x:,}".replace(",", "."))
```

Вывод:

```
19.783.598.745.098.604.980.923.980.423.490.945.098.398.569.485.694.865.095.480.678
```

Answer (score 0):

Смотри вот так можно (я подобное делал для своего Дискорд-бота):

```
chislo = str(19783598745098604980923980423490945098398569485694865095480678)
kol_tochek = len(chislo) // 3
i = kol_tochek
result = ""
mesto = len(chislo)
if kol_tochek > 0:
     while i > 0:
          result = "."  + chislo[(mesto-3):mesto] + result
          i -= 1
          mesto -= 3
result = chislo[0:mesto]+result
if result[0] == ".":
     result = result[1:]
print(result)
```

Comment: Судя по другим ответам, я опоздал лет так на пять)

Comment: Ну, format в Python 2.7 уже есть (на более старых версиях надо смотреть, не знаю точно), а он в 2010 году вышел, значит больше чем на 10)

Comment: А, даже в 2.6 уже есть (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), значит лет на 15)

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоватся встроенной функцией format().

```
'{:,}'.format(number).replace(',', '.')
```

Где number - ваше число в Int.
Пользуйтесь!

Comment: Чуть опоздали: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1558126/1365. В целом, format - это "прошлый век", сейчас уже f-строки актуальны.